# Quickly toggle a boolean property of objects in an array based on a list of attribute values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, updating

I have an array of objects like:

```
[{type: 'marker', name: 'somename', id: '123abc321', lat: 123.00, lng: 32.00, educationRegion: 'someregion', seDistrict: 'sometype', sector: 'somesector', selected: false, shownOnMap: true, listed: false}, {type: 'marker', name: 'somename', id: '123abc322', lat: 123.00, lng: 32.00, educationRegion: 'someregion', seDistrict: 'sometype', sector: 'somesector', selected: false, shownOnMap: true, listed: false}, {type: 'marker', name: 'somename', id: '123abc323', lat: 123.00, lng: 32.00, educationRegion: 'someregion', seDistrict: 'sometype', sector: 'somesector', selected: false, shownOnMap: true, listed: false}]
```

The maximum number of objects in the array is around 7600

I am struggling to find a fast way of flipping the 'selected' property from true to false or vice versa of every object whose id is included in an array of id values like:

```
['123abc322', '123abc323']
```

The supplier array of id values could include ALL the object ids and will often be ~2000 ids.

So if the object.id field is in the supplied array I want to swap the object.selected to !object.selected

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend converting your array of IDs into a `Set`. Then, it's a matter of doing one pass over your array and, if the `Set` contains the element's ID, toggle the `selected` property.

Note that this method modifies the objects in the array. If you need to not mutate the input, you could use a `map`.

**Mutating the input:**

```js
const arr = [{type: 'marker', name: 'somename', id: '123abc321', lat: 123.00, lng: 32.00, educationRegion: 'someregion', seDistrict: 'sometype', sector: 'somesector', selected: false, shownOnMap: true, listed: false}, {type: 'marker', name: 'somename', id: '123abc322', lat: 123.00, lng: 32.00, educationRegion: 'someregion', seDistrict: 'sometype', sector: 'somesector', selected: false, shownOnMap: true, listed: false}, {type: 'marker', name: 'somename', id: '123abc323', lat: 123.00, lng: 32.00, educationRegion: 'someregion', seDistrict: 'sometype', sector: 'somesector', selected: false, shownOnMap: true, listed: false}];

const ids = new Set(['123abc322', '123abc323']);

arr.forEach(el => {
  if (ids.has(el.id)) {
    el.selected = !el.selected;
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

**Not mutating the input:**

```js
const arr = [{type: 'marker', name: 'somename', id: '123abc321', lat: 123.00, lng: 32.00, educationRegion: 'someregion', seDistrict: 'sometype', sector: 'somesector', selected: false, shownOnMap: true, listed: false}, {type: 'marker', name: 'somename', id: '123abc322', lat: 123.00, lng: 32.00, educationRegion: 'someregion', seDistrict: 'sometype', sector: 'somesector', selected: false, shownOnMap: true, listed: false}, {type: 'marker', name: 'somename', id: '123abc323', lat: 123.00, lng: 32.00, educationRegion: 'someregion', seDistrict: 'sometype', sector: 'somesector', selected: false, shownOnMap: true, listed: false}];

const ids = new Set(['123abc322', '123abc323']);

const newArr = arr.map(el => {
  if (!ids.has(el.id)) return el;

  return {
    ...el,
    selected: !el.selected
  }
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, both options worked well but still no performance gain. I'm still looking at ~11 sec to process 270 items against the full array of 7600.

Comment: Quick update: it turns out that the delay was the component rendering the result of the update rather than the update itself. Sigh. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything with a single line of code, here's a code example:

```js
let array = [{
    type: "marker",
    name: "somename",
    id: "123abc321",
    lat: 123.0,
    lng: 32.0,
    educationRegion: "someregion",
    seDistrict: "sometype",
    sector: "somesector",
    selected: false,
    shownOnMap: true,
    listed: false,
  },
  {
    type: "marker",
    name: "somename",
    id: "123abc322",
    lat: 123.0,
    lng: 32.0,
    educationRegion: "someregion",
    seDistrict: "sometype",
    sector: "somesector",
    selected: false,
    shownOnMap: true,
    listed: false,
  },
  {
    type: "marker",
    name: "somename",
    id: "123abc323",
    lat: 123.0,
    lng: 32.0,
    educationRegion: "someregion",
    seDistrict: "sometype",
    sector: "somesector",
    selected: false,
    shownOnMap: true,
    listed: false,
  },
];

let ids = ['123abc322', '123abc323'];

// .filter() create a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
// .map() run a function for everyone of the remaining objects and flip the "selected" value.

array.filter(x => ids.includes(x.id)).map(x => x.selected = !x.selected);
console.log(array);
```

Hope It's what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it totally worked but unfortunately didn't give me any performance gain. I'm still looking at ~11 sec to process 270 items against the full array of 7600.